# How to place a variable inside of 'use trait'

Tags: php

```
return (new class { use \App\Traits\{$App.'Api'};
```

anyone know how to put variable into use trait?

all my traits contain Api at the end. (ex. `trait AbcApi { }` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement, it's not possible in PHP right now. Effectively, you are trying to dynamically change the source code of the class. Similarly, you can't dynamically choose a class name, an extends or implements clause, property names, etc.

You will need to generate the PHP code and run it through [eval](https://php.net/eval), or pre-process it into a source file and include that.